# number of connected components

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

we have `n` nodes and corresponding value associated with each node is represented by an Array `A[]`. For any `i` and `j` where `(1<=i,j<=n and i!=j)` there is an edge b/w them if `GCD(A[i],A[j])==1`. We have to find the number of connected components in the graph formed by them.

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 2⋅10^5

1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 2⋅10^5
```

time is **0.5** sec.

I am solving this by using disjoint set in `O(n^2 log n)` time,But it exceeds the time limit.

I can also find the prime factors of all `A[i]` in `O(nlogn)` time.But not able to utilize it to find solution.

Comment: the DFS algorithm can be converted to use adjacency matrix, and solve this in O(E + V) or O(N^2) worst case in your case.

Comment: @ShaharA what about GCD . it takes logn time.

Comment: To clarify: you want the number of connected components, not necessarily the connected components? The graph looks as sort of reverse of grouping based on common prime-factors, e.g. if you {4,6,9} there would be two components {4,9] and {6} - but if you then extend it with 5 to {4,6,9,5} there is only one component. I don't know if that in combination suggests a simple fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can build bipartite graph where left part contains array values and right part contains primes, in O(nlogn), as you wrote.

Then for every vertice of the left part we should find what (left part) vertices are at distance 2 from it (in graph) and make connections to all the rest vertices (in disjoint set structure).

Perhaps the worst case of the second stage (using BFS with depth 2) is quadratic but seems it might be rather fast in practice.

Comment: can u write psudo code after making bipartite graph(i.e. which node on left side are not at distance 2 from it) in O(n^2) or O(nlogn).

Comment: Two steps of BFS (first step to divisor, second to element with  GCD>1, mark it). Then all unmarked ones have GCD=1 with current item. I did not check details thoroughly, so I might mistake about O(n^2)

Comment: thanks bro, it works for O(n^2). If u find any way to find its solution in O(nlogn), then please comment.

Comment: Sadly, I don't see O(nlogn) approach, but `2⋅10^5` limit points to such desired complexity.

Comment: We can mark mutual primes during factorization (keeping table of dividends for every prime), but it is still quadratic method.

Comment: O(nlogn) solution is only possible if we iterate all the node of bipartite graph only once.